# Refresh Form1 dataGrid from another form c# winform

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagrid

I've made 2 forms. 1 "Main form" and another like "Modal window" for data insert.

On Form1, i have this code:

```
public void CargarDataGrid_Estudiantes()
    {
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
        con.Open();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("showStudent", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pid_School", Login.ID_SCHOOL_LOGIN);

        MySqlDataAdapter DataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable DataTable = new DataTable();

        DataAdapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataAdapter.Fill(DataTable);

        dataGrid_Estudiantes.DataSource = DataTable;
        dataGrid_Estudiantes.Columns[0].HeaderCell.Value = "id_Student";
        dataGrid_Estudiantes.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        Bla bla bla bla bla........................
    }
```

I tried to refresh my grid using this code on userControl of form2 "Close button":

```
private void btn_cerrarModal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Pantallas.Estudiantes estu = new Estudiantes();
        estu.CargarDataGrid_Estudiantes();

        ((Modal)this.TopLevelControl).Close();
    }
```

But dosnt work. What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: the *grid* doesnt need to be refreshed, the *data* does.

Answer (score 0):

you cant create a new instance of `Pantallas.Estudiantes` (in form2) and expect to access another instance (the "original" instance of form1/Pantallas.Estudiantes).

use the `DialogResult` value of form 2 in order to determine if there is a need to refresh `Form1`:

calling `Form2` **from** `Form1`:

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            if (f2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)

            {
                // refresh form
                CargarDataGrid_Estudiantes();
            } 
        }
```

**user presses close button on `form2`:**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            this.Close();
        }
```

in another button on `Form2` you can do that piece of code, if there is a case that you dont want to refresh Form1:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
                this.Close();
            }
```